# WAN is faster than WLAN even though it's an additional step

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, speed

Yep, the title is right. My WLAN connections are unbearably slow, I'm talking 10 k**b**ps. I have done many tests and tried to find the problem, including trying this on different computers and changing the locations too. My actual ISP connection is for 200Mbps up and down, which it sometimes exceeds and even hits 250Mbps up and down. I have a Huawei HG8145V, both machines have been adjusted for the firewall.

Info

Gateway: 10.0.0.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Server: 10.0.0.2
Client: 10.0.0.5
Public IP (Not my actual public IP, just there to make results easy to read): 1.1.1.1

Tests (performed with iperf3 and an HTTP server)
*** All public IP tests were performed with ports that were forwarded in the router. Bytes are written with a capital B, bits are lowercase b.

Sender - Receiver = Speed

10.0.0.2 - 10.0.0.5 = ~10-15Kbps
10.0.0.5 - 10.0.0.2 = ~10-15Kbps
1.1.1.1 - 10.0.0.2 = ~80-90Mbps
(I forwarded both machines' ports)
1.1.1.1 - 10.0.0.5 = ~80-90Mbps
(This one is kind of useless, but anyways)
10.0.0.2 - 10.0.0.2 = ~30-31Gbps
10.0.0.5 - 10.0.0.5 = ~5-8Gbps

What is going on...

Edit: The wording was a little unclear, but what I mean to say with the 1.1.1.1 IP tests, is that I had forwarded the port required by iperf3 on both the machines so that I could make the iperf3 server available on the public IP. This is the main point that I am trying to put forth, that my WLAN is very slow, but my WAN/Public net is much faster even though it's an additional step.

10.0.0.2 - 10.0.0.5 is a LAN connection, whereas
1.1.1.1 (10.0.0.2's port forwarded) - 10.0.0.5 is a WAN connection, and so is
1.1.1.1 (10.0.0.5's port forwarded) - 10.0.0.2

Comment: Can we see some ping stats from the wireless lan client to the router. I want to see if you are losing packets. As well as from the router to the client.

Comment: With the "1.1.1.1" tests, were you running iperf3 directly _on_ the router, or were you relying on port-forwarding to do something else? It's very unclear that you list 1.1.1.1 as a sender but then talk about port forwarding implying that 1.1.1.1 _isn't_ the actual sender.

Comment: Sure, 10.0.0.2 is running Void Linux and 10.0.0.5 is running Windows 10, I'm not sure if that matters, but I've tried this with another machine using macOS and the results are pretty much the same. I have pinged with 1024 bytes in both cases.

Pastebin for 10.0.0.2 (pinging to gateway): https://pastebin.com/7WpDcFNE
Pastebin for 10.0.0.5 (same): https://pastebin.com/8SZmpMTV

Comment: @user1686 Sorry for the unclear wording, but what I mean is that I tried forwarding the ports from both the machines and using them as the server and client interchangeably so that I could confirm that it wasn't a single computer's fault. iperf3 was running on the computers and not the router. I was relying on port forwarding to make the iperf3 server available on my public IP, which as you can see had faster speeds.

Comment: you just have a very slow wifi. This is usually due to a poor choice of wifi channel (but also could be due to local interferences (microwave, baby monitor, etc, depending on what kind of wifi tech you use). Always use a cable when performance are needed, and if you can't use a cable: do tests (and know that every neighbours equipment may change their channel automatically too, making the test limited in time, and the problem may reoccur in the future..). use mainly channels: 1, 6 or 11 (others overlap). At my house, channel change make it jump from 60kbps to 1.1mbps (note: >100mbps via cable)

Comment: (I cite the wifi speed from memory, and memory is probably false... but it was a x20 difference)

Comment: why is a physical cable so much faster? (unless you use a hub...) : https://www.networkcomputing.com/networking/wireless-beginners-part-2-avoiding-collisions # ie, one wifi, only 1 machine can emit at a time, and you share the channel with potentially many other neighbours)

Comment: The speed in tens of kbps is curious, but overall the post is based on an incorrect assumption: "1.1.1.1 (10.0.0.2's port forwarded) - 10.0.0.5" is _not_ a WAN connection. A router's "WAN address" is always assigned to the router itself, and you are _only_ sending packets through the router and back -- they never go out through your physical WAN line. (And of course, "WAN" and "WLAN" are not mutually exclusive -- if 10.0.0.5 is a Wi-Fi device, then even if those packets _did_ go through WAN they _still_ have to go through Wi-Fi first in order to leave the device.)

Comment: @user1686 The reason why I assumed this is because I tried it with one of my friends, he got iperf3 and connected to my server using my public IP, and he got speeds of up to 90Mbps. I understand how WAN and LAN work, that's not the problem here. Plus you mention they never go out through my actual WAN line, how is that possible in the scenario I just mentioned? And if that was indeed the case, that it was just going through my router, then shouldn't 10.0.0.2 - 10.0.0.5 provide the same speed?

Comment: @OlivierDulac I totally agree that physical cables are faster, and I know that that's the only way if you want high performance, but currently, I would need a thunderbolt 2 to RJ45 adapter if I wanted to connect my Linux machine, which is a 2015 MacBook, to my newer machine and I can't find any in-stock right now. I'll try changing the channels, but I didn't understand what you meant by slow Wi-Fi. If I had slow Wi-Fi how would I be getting ~210Mbps download speeds (externally) on both devices at the same time? My main confusion is the huge difference in WLAN performance.

Comment: I was not talking about the scenario you just mentioned, and I couldn't have, _because you had not mentioned it then._ One difference between the two local tests is that packets between 10.0.0.x hosts are directly forwarded by the Wi-Fi AP (hardware bridge), while packets which involve port forwarding are sent to the router's MAC so the AP forwards the packets to the CPU (for NAT hairpinning) which then sends them back out. I don't know why this causes a speed difference but I have a slight suspicion that it has something to do with the added delay helping.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Anyways, I'm looking into this as much as I can, but this is as far as I could get, so I came to superuser. Thanks for the help anyway, I guess I should look into my router settings then?